# Closed form of coprime numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Denoting primes $p_n$, I'm interested in the order of the set of natural numbers below a given limit that are divisible by the nth prime, but not by any smaller prime. Explicitly, with $A(M,n) = \{ x\leq M : p_n | x$ and $p_k\nmid x, \forall k<n \}$, what is $|A(M,n)|$?

For small n some case work gives a formula, but no promise of generalizing to all n. Also, if take $B_n = \lim_{M\to \infty} |A(M,n)|/M$, we have a nice closed form $$ B_n = \frac{1}{p_n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{p_{k}-1 }{p_{k}}. $$ However, this is also not quite sufficient. I've been unable to find a name for $A(M,n)$ in terms of known objects, or bounds on its order. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A "$k$-rough number" is a positive integer whose prime factors are all greater than or equal to $k$. The Buchstab function is used to count rough numbers. You want the number of $p_n$-rough numbers, minus the number of $p_{n+1}$-rough numbers.

Comment: Or, the $p_n$-rough numbers up to $M/p_n$.